# RegEx to replace @ unless it is preceded by /

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regular expression that will be used to replace @ with /@, unless the the @ is preceded by <.  I have been fiddling with [RegExHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) to try to accomplish this, but it is not quite right.  It is important to note that I am fairly clueless when it comes to regular expressions.

Here is what I have tried:

Regular Expression
`[^<]\@`

Replacement String
`&/@`

Target String
`Flip@`

This almost works, in that it will not replace Flip<@.  But then it does not work because it replaces Flip@ to Fli/@.  Basically, I need to keep the original character in the case that the symbol is not preceded by an angle bracket.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you've worded is exactly what the definition of a *negative lookbehind assertion* is.

```
(?<!<)@
```

In general,

```
(?<!foo)bar
```

means, "bar" not following "foo". A *positive* lookbehind,

```
(?<=foo)bar
```

would mean, oppositely, "bar" *following* "foo".

There are also look*aheads*, *e.g.*

```
bar(?=foo)
```

meaning "bar" followed by "foo".

Comment: As a group, these are called "zero-width assertions"

Comment: Thanks for the added bit about the look-ahead, as I needed the other bracket too.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your expression does not work as expected is that your expression captures the character preceding the `@` sign, making it part of the replacement target. You need to change `[^<]` with `(?<!<)` to use the non-capturing [*negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The final expression should look like this:

```
(?<!<)\@
```