# Remove all digits from a Python string except digits followed by period

Tags: python, regex, string

Say I have a string:

```
some_string = 'lorum ipsum 123 bar foo 1. \
               more text 46 here 2. some more text here \
               3. and even more text here 789'
```

How could I remove all the digits except for ones trailed with a period using Regex (or any other method)?

Ideal outcome:

```
some_string = 'lorum ipsum bar foo 1. \
               more text here 2. some more text here \
               3. and even more text here'
```

I'm a Regex beginner and have only tried `[0-9]\.` but this highlights what I want to keep.

I'd like to keep digits in the form of `1.`, `2.`, etc

Thank you.

Comment: What output do you expect for:  `"1. I like Python 3.7 but I don't like Python 2.7"` ?

Comment: You will be asked "what have you tried?"  You want 1 to many digits that do not follow a period.  You can test your regexes here https://pythex.org/, then use the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to substitute  substrings.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour].

Comment: So if you had `21.42` you’d want to keep only `1.`, not `21.`? Also, what’s the rule you want that removes the extra space either before or after the `123` but not both (so you end up with `ipsum bar` rather than `ipsumbar` or `ipsum  bar`? And is the space required, so `c64` would stay `c64`, or should it turn into `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `[0-9](?!\.)` as your expression.

This is an example of a look ahead, essentially asking if the next character is not a '.' then consider it.

If you are looking to have multiple digits such as 41. then you could also use

```
[0-9](?![0-9]+\.|\.)
```

I would look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721992/regex-to-replace-unless-it-is-preceded-by) for an example of look behinds and look aheads as well as having a play [here](https://regex101.com/) to test it.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wwbpoN/1)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen - Edited to reflect this.

Comment: You can simplify your second regex to `[0-9](?![0-9]*\.)`, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/1HObgT/1).

Comment: Excellent @TimBiegeleisen Half the steps, still learning regexp myself.

Answer (score 1):

We can try matching on the following pattern:

```
\s*[0-9]+([^.]|$)
```

Here, we match some optional whitespace, followed by any number of digits, which in turn are followed by any character *other* than dot.  We capture this non dot character, and then use it in the replacement.

```
some_string = 'lorum ipsum 123 bar foo 1. \
               more text 46 here 2. some more text here \
               3. and even more text here 789'
some_string = re.sub(r"\s*[0-9]+([^.]|$)", r"\1", some_string)

print(some_string)

lorum ipsum bar foo 1.                more text here 2. some more text here
            3. and even more text here
```

### Demo

I assume that the digits you want to retain never have a decimal component.